# Is it possible for the background-image of a parent element to take precedence over a child element's background-color?

Tags: css, background-image, background-color

Here is a simplified example:

```css
.container {
    background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/67636/rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg?auto=format%2Ccompress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500');
    height: 300px;
    width: 500px;
}

.child {
    /* This takes precedence over background-image of the parent .container */
    background-color: red;
    width: 100px;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">
    hello
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pXjWOj

The red background colour of the child element takes precedence over the background image. While this would normally be the desired behaviour, I have a use case where I need the background image of the parent to take precedence.

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  padding: 50px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 320px;
  overflow: scroll;
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
  margin: 0 auto;
  
  
     background-image:
    /* Shadows */ 
    linear-gradient(to right, white, white),
    linear-gradient(to right, white, white),
/* Shadow covers */ 
    linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0,.15), rgba(255,255,255,0)),
    linear-gradient(to left, rgba(0,0,0,.15), rgba(255,255,255,0));   

  background-position: left center, right center, left center, right center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: 10px 100%, 10px 100%, 5px 100%, 5px 100%;
  background-attachment: local, local, scroll, scroll;
}

.el {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  scroll-snap-align: center;
  min-width: 300px;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  background
}

html {
  background: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="scrollbox">
  <div class="el">Jello</div>
  <div class="el">Hello</div>
  <div class="el">Hello</div>
  <div class="el">Hello</div>
  <div class="el">Hello</div>
  <div class="el">Hello</div>
  <div class="el">Hello</div>
  <div class="el">Hello</div>
    <div class="el">Jello</div>
  <div class="el">Hello</div>
  <div class="el">Hello</div>
  <div class="el">Hello</div>
  <div class="el">Hello</div>
  <div class="el">Hello</div>
  <div class="el">Hello</div>
  <div class="el">Hello</div>
    <div class="el">Jello</div>
  <div class="el">Hello</div>
  <div class="el">Hello</div>
  <div class="el">Hello</div>
  <div class="el">Hello</div>
  <div class="el">Hello</div>
  <div class="el">Hello</div>
  <div class="el">Hello</div>
    <div class="el">Jello</div>
  <div class="el">Hello</div>
  <div class="el">Hello</div>
  <div class="el">Hello</div>
  <div class="el">Hello</div>
  <div class="el">Hello</div>
  <div class="el">Hello</div>
  <div class="el">Hello</div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VJLQzd

In this example I have shadows on the parent element using `background-image` that tells the user there are more elements to scroll. However the `background-color` of the child elements take precedence over the parent's `background-image` shadow.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `z-index` of the `.el` elements to -1 and you get the desired effect visually. This may intefere with how you want your users to interface with the elements though... Hope it helps.

---

## Demo

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  padding: 50px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 320px;
  overflow: scroll;
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
  margin: 0 auto;
  
  
     background-image:
    /* Shadows */ 
    linear-gradient(to right, white, white),
    linear-gradient(to right, white, white),
/* Shadow covers */ 
    linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0,.15), rgba(255,255,255,0)),
    linear-gradient(to left, rgba(0,0,0,.15), rgba(255,255,255,0));   

  background-position: left center, right center, left center, right center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: 10px 100%, 10px 100%, 5px 100%, 5px 100%;
  background-attachment: local, local, scroll, scroll;
}

.el {
  z-index: -1;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  scroll-snap-align: center;
  min-width: 300px;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  background
}

html {
  background: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="scrollbox">
  <div class="el">Jello</div>
  <div class="el">Hello</div>
  <div class="el">Hello</div>
  <div class="el">Hello</div>
  <div class="el">Hello</div>
  <div class="el">Hello</div>
  <div class="el">Hello</div>
  <div class="el">Hello</div>
    <div class="el">Jello</div>
  <div class="el">Hello</div>
  <div class="el">Hello</div>
  <div class="el">Hello</div>
  <div class="el">Hello</div>
  <div class="el">Hello</div>
  <div class="el">Hello</div>
  <div class="el">Hello</div>
    <div class="el">Jello</div>
  <div class="el">Hello</div>
  <div class="el">Hello</div>
  <div class="el">Hello</div>
  <div class="el">Hello</div>
  <div class="el">Hello</div>
  <div class="el">Hello</div>
  <div class="el">Hello</div>
    <div class="el">Jello</div>
  <div class="el">Hello</div>
  <div class="el">Hello</div>
  <div class="el">Hello</div>
  <div class="el">Hello</div>
  <div class="el">Hello</div>
  <div class="el">Hello</div>
  <div class="el">Hello</div>
</div>
```